# how to reduce time while saving tiles(images) by gov.ca.maps.tiles.TileCreator?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to generate tiles which are a collection of polygons using TileCreator. I am using methods like, tileCreator.renderData(), tileCreator.saveAll(). Both of these working fine. But saveAll() method takes lots of time to put an image in filesystem.

```
TileCreator tileCreator= new TileCreator(
                    directory,
                    zoomLevel,
                    new TileRenderer[] { new ValueAsColoredShapeRenderer(color) {
                    } });

            Double [][]kmllatlonbounds=new Double[][]{{1000.0,1000.0},{-1000.0,-1000.0}};
            tileCreator.kmllatlon=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
            for(int i=0;i<jsArray2.length();i++){

                JSONArray bound = jsArray2.getJSONArray(i);
                //System.out.println("Zoom Level: "+zoomLevel+" Bound[0]: "+bound.getDouble(0)+"Bound[1]: "+bound.getDouble(1));
                Double lon = bound.getDouble(0);
                Double lat = bound.getDouble(1);
                if(lat>kmllatlonbounds[1][0])
                {
                    kmllatlonbounds[1][0]=lat;
                }
                if(lat<kmllatlonbounds[0][0])
                {
                    kmllatlonbounds[0][0]=lat;
                }
                if(lon>kmllatlonbounds[1][1])
                {
                    kmllatlonbounds[1][1]=lon;
                }
                if(lon<kmllatlonbounds[0][1])
                {
                    kmllatlonbounds[0][1]=lon;      
                }

                double[] meters = tileCreator.getMercator().LatLonToMeters(lat, lon);
                int[] metersToPixels = tileCreator.getMercator().MetersToPixels(meters[0],meters[1], zoomLevel);

                ArrayList<Double> tmplatlon=new ArrayList<Double>();
                tmplatlon.add((double)metersToPixels[1]);
                tmplatlon.add((double)metersToPixels[0]);
                tileCreator.kmllatlon.add(tmplatlon);
                }
            tileCreator.renderData(kmllatlonbounds);
            tileCreator.saveAll();
```

Internally i am using ImageIo class for Read/Write Operations. I think problem is with ImageIo, But can't solve.
Can any one please help me? Because i want 100% Optimization as it is taking hours of time to generate tiles...

Comment: You can put long running operations in Threads.  How do you know what's taking the processing time?  Have you benchmarked your code?  Since you haven't provided runnable code, all we can do is guess.

Comment: I ran with multithreading. it reduced time efficiently. But is there any alternative to ImageIO. I want to use nio api of java which is in java7. Can it help me?

Comment: I just looked through the Java 8 javadoc for the nio packages.  I didn't see anything related to image processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any limitation of memory, you can reduce the frequency of SaveAll() by increasing the cache size in ImageCache.java